# CSS: Overlay two images perfectly on all screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I have two images. One is a picture that has rounded edges, the other is a picture of a round frame. I want to place the frame over the picture so that it looks like it is a single image. 
I am struggling with the CSS to do this because on different screen sizes, it does not remain constant.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="picture.png" id="profile"/>
    <img src="frame.png" id="frame"/>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
div.image   {position: relative;}

img#profile {width: 250px;
            border-radius: 50%}

img#frame   {width: 250px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 100;}
```

I want the result to look like this (the blue is the picture `#profile` and the orange is the frame `#frame`:

[image]

In addition, this needs to stay this way regardless of the screen size so using `left` values does not really work.

With the above markup, the images are doing this:

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: use padding for img#frame no need to set left or top

Comment: The padding works really well. Can maybe explain to me why that is?

Comment: @ALR you can also use left:0 on img#frame [ https://jsfiddle.net/8ogs98pz/ ] sorry for bad quality img .

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any pictures. So, I used css styles. You can remove the background color and add your pic urls.

```
div.image {
    position: relative;
}
img#profile {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
img#frame {
    width: 270px;
    height: 270px;
    background: tomato;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7bmomq2o/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix it yourself whenever you change the size.

```
div.image {
position: fixed;
margin: 100px;
}
img#profile {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background: skyblue;
border-radius: 100%;
z-index: 100;
position: absolute;

}
img#frame {
width: 270px;
height: 270px;
background: orange;
border-radius: 100%;
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
top:-10px;
left:-10px;
}
```